# A URL opens fine in google chrome(mobile phone) but same url is giving outdate browser message when opened using webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to open a site which heavily used html5 in an android application using webview, but it gives outdate browser version message. However when I open same url in chrome browser in my phone it works fine( In developer option webview implementation is set to same chrome browser).